# cannot connect to ec2 instance created by packer image

Tags: amazon-ec2, packer

I have written packer script to create image in aws. After executing the packer script it is running a ec2 instance which is using pem file created by packer. But how can I know which pem file packer is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packer creates a temporary SSH key-pair (of which a `.pem` file is the private half). You do not need this temporary key pair to access the resulting AMI. As with Amazon's official AMIs, or an AMI that you create from a snapshot of an existing machine, you can choose any new or existing SSH key-pair when you launch a new EC2 instance backed by your AMI.